# Is Yarn repository separate from NPM or does it use NPM repository behind the scenes?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, pnpm, yarn-v2

I'm considering using Yarn or PNPM instead of NPM.

However, I don't know if they have separate repositories or if they both use the same repository.

The reason that I'm asking this is because if they use separate repositories, then I should be worried about some packages being available in NPM repository, but absent in other repositories, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. Yarn registry is just a CNAME of `npm`.

To know more you can visit the official yarn [docs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#why-registryyarnpkgcom-does-facebook-track-us).